# Not able to mount Azure File Share as a drive on my local machine

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have created a storage account and a Point to Site VPN to connect my on-premises system. I wanted to mount the file share as a drive on my local machine. Even after the VPN was created and I was able to successfully connect to a VM in the Virtual Network using its private IP address, but somehow, the mounting is not happening. It says that the network path does not exist.

I tried troubleshooting using the following link, but it did not help. It says that the script is not digitally signed.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Troubleshooting-tool-for-a9fa1fe5

Also, there is an error creating the private endpoint on Storage Account. The error says "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state failed." It is a complete mess. Please help

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Azure File Share is publicly accessible, you don't need to use a P2S VPN connection to mount Azure File Share as a drive on the local machine.

To mount the Azure file share with PowerShell on Windows, you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows).

```
$resourceGroupName = "<your-resource-group-name>"
$storageAccountName = "<your-storage-account-name>"
$fileShareName = "<your-file-share-name>"

# These commands require you to be logged into your Azure account, run Login-AzAccount if you haven't
# already logged in.
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName
$storageAccountKeys = Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName
$fileShare = Get-AzStorageShare -Context $storageAccount.Context | Where-Object { 
    $_.Name -eq $fileShareName -and $_.IsSnapshot -eq $false
}

if ($fileShare -eq $null) {
    throw [System.Exception]::new("Azure file share not found")
}

# The value given to the root parameter of the New-PSDrive cmdlet is the host address for the storage account, 
# <storage-account>.file.core.windows.net for Azure Public Regions. $fileShare.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.Host is 
# used because non-Public Azure regions, such as sovereign clouds or Azure Stack deployments, will have different 
# hosts for Azure file shares (and other storage resources).
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $storageAccountKeys[0].Value -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "AZURE\$($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)", $password
New-PSDrive -Name <desired-drive-letter> -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\$($fileShare.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.Host)\$($fileShare.Name)" -Credential $credential -Persist
```

For Linux, you could get more details about [using Azure Files with Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux).

### Edit

[Azure Files provides two main types of endpoints for accessing Azure file shares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-networking-endpoints?tabs=azure-portal):

- **Public endpoints**, which have a public IP address and can be accessed from anywhere in the world.
- **Private endpoints**, which exist within a virtual network and have a private IP address from within the address space of that virtual network.

By default, the azure file provided public endpoint that you can access from anywhere but if you have a VPN connection, it accesses via internal private IP address.

Without a VPN connection, you can follow the above steps in that document. To use a P2S VPN connection with Azure Files, you don't need to open up port 445. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-configure-p2s-vpn-windows) are the full steps.

First, you need to configure a P2S VPN connection for each client that wants to connect.

Then follow the example to mount the share, list the root directory of the share to prove the share is actually mounted, and then unmount the share.

```
$myShareToMount = "<file-share>"

$storageAccountKeys = Get-AzStorageAccountKey `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -Name $storageAccountName
$storageAccountKey = ConvertTo-SecureString `
    -String $storageAccountKeys[0].Value `
    -AsPlainText `
    -Force

$nic = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceId $privateEndpoint.NetworkInterfaces[0].Id
$storageAccountPrivateIP = $nic.IpConfigurations[0].PrivateIpAddress

Invoke-Command `
    -Session $sessions `
    -ArgumentList  `
        $storageAccountName, `
        $storageAccountKey, `
        $storageAccountPrivateIP, `
        $myShareToMount `
    -ScriptBlock {
        $storageAccountName = $args[0]
        $storageAccountKey = $args[1]
        $storageAccountPrivateIP = $args[2]
        $myShareToMount = $args[3]

        $credential = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new(
            "AZURE\$storageAccountName", 
            $storageAccountKey)

        New-PSDrive `
            -Name Z `
            -PSProvider FileSystem `
            -Root "\\$storageAccountPrivateIP\$myShareToMount" `
            -Credential $credential `
            -Persist | Out-Null
        Get-ChildItem -Path Z:\
        Remove-PSDrive -Name Z
    }
```

Unfortunately, it is not possible to mount the share **persistently over PowerShell remoting**. To mount persistently, see [Use an Azure file share with Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows).

Comment: I already followed this article and also I created the environment from the Portal as well, but it does not work for me.

Comment: Also, it can be used via the storage explorer, but just for the ease of use, we need to mount it. Also, I am not sure when you say publicly available.... Can you explain?

Comment: I mean by default azure file provided public endpoint that you can access from anywhere but if you have a VPN connection, it accesses via internal private IP address. You could check my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have followed the same article that has been referenced in your points above. Unfortunately, it seems to be a subscription level issue, which I have raised with Microsoft as well. It errors out while creating Private endpoints intermittently.

Also, the VPN connection needs to be created only once, and we can distribute the VPN client to any user who wishes to connect via VPN. With the same, we also need to share the private and root certificates for VPN client installation to work.

I am still at it and will post the solution as soon as I hear back from MS.