# Azure File Shares drive map password prompt

Tags: azure-storage

I'm having a problem mapping a file share on Azurefiles using Active directory authentication.Storage account already connected to on premise domain and i have a hybrid domain setup.

File share can be mount using the storage account key without any issue.However, when i try to map the share from a domain joined account without storage account key it gives the following error.

System error 86 has occurred.

The specified network password is not correct.

The AD user account was already added to "Storage File Data SMB Share Contributor" role as well.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the error message you can refer to the suggestion mentioned [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8f998372-f927-47da-808f-a5e290591a58/error-86-when-trying-to-access-an-azure-storage-account-file-share?forum=windowsazuredata) [Error 86 Specified password is incorrect](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/49481)

Active Directory authentication over SMB for Azure file shares: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-auth-active-directory-enable#mount-a-file-share-from-a-domain-joined-vm

Azure Active Directory Domain Services authentication on Azure Files:ht tps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-auth-active-directory-domain-service-enable#mount-a-file-share-from-a-domain-joined-vm

For additional information please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60923655/not-able-to-mount-azure-file-share-as-a-drive-on-my-local-machine) also, which gives an idea on your query

[Troubleshoot Azure Files problems in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-windows-file-connection-problems)

Comment: The suggestions should go in the answer directly, rather than links.
At the very least, the most likely answer should be included here.
We have all been victims of Microsoft deciding to reorganise their docs breaking existing links.